# Multiple matching groups regex

Tags: regex

I thought that surrounding expressions with brackets allowed you to do multiple matches.

```regex
/(^(.*?)\?).(([?&])([^=]+)=([^&]+))/g
```

The above regex should first match everything before `?`, then the second one should match all of the URL Parameters.

> search.php?make=8&vehicle_type=car&location_path=used&sort=nis&p=

Both work perfect alone, but not together, I get no matches.

Comment: You get no matches as you are matching 3 characters with this part `\?).(([?&])` where you only want to match either `?` or `&` with just `[?&]` The pattern can look like `^([^?&]*)([?&])([^=]+)=([^&]+)` but note that you will only have 1 group for the key and 1 group for the value after it. https://regex101.com/r/pIqsUw/1 Depending on the tool or language there are different ways to get all the key value pairs (or parsing the url using a parser)

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to get 2 matching groups, one with the url, and the other with all the parameters

Answer (score 0):

There are no matches,  as this part of the pattern `\?).(([?&])` expects to match 3 characters: `?`, any character due to the dot, and either `?` or `&`

If you want 2 separate groups, 1 for the url, and the second one with all the parameters, you can match the first key/value pair and optionally repeat more key/value pairs.

```
^([^?&]*)[?&]([^=]+=[^&]*(?:&[^=]+=[^&]*)*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^?&]*)` Capture **group 1**, match any character except `?` and `&`
- `[?&]` Match either `?` or `&`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^=]+=[^&]*` Match a key/value pair, exluding the `=` before and excluding the `&` after
  - `(?:&[^=]+=[^&]*)*` Optionally repeat the previous pattern with a leading `&`
- `)` Close capture group 2
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GIhGCn/1)

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question 2 different ways

## Match 2 groups: the url + the parameters string

```
(^([^?]*)|([^?]*)$)
```

Will match:

- **search.php**
- make=8&vehicle_type=car&location_path=used&sort=nis&p=

This works because we look for a string of any non-? character until the first is found, OR ("|") a string of non-? characters that go to the end of the test string.

https://regex101.com/r/uD5SGG/1

## Match multiple groups: the url + one group per parameter

```
(^([^?]*)|([\w_]*=[\w_]*))
```

Will match:

- **search.php**
- make=8
- vehicle_type=car
- location_path=used
- sort=nis
- p=

Note that the & do not match. Again, we use | as in "OR". `[\w_]*` indicates that we look for parameters composed of letters or "_".

https://regex101.com/r/2VL6i0/1